# starting thread using jboss5 thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, classloader, threadpool, jboss5.x

My application, running in JBoss 5, needs to start a thread to perform some work asynchronously. The code uses the 'ThreadPoolMBean' to use a thread from JBoss's own thread pool -- this worked in JBoss 4 but now seems to be running up against classloader problems, since I get this exception:

```
14:52:15,918 WARN [org.jboss.util.threadpool.RunnableTaskWrapper] (JBoss System Threads(1)-413:) Unhandled throwable for runnable: application.NSP@4c80c3ab () 
    org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:596)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:371)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:127)
    at application.NSP.run(NotfallStopperProzess.java:105)
    at org.jboss.util.threadpool.RunnableTaskWrapper.run(RunnableTaskWrapper.java:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: interface org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionWrapper is not visible from class loader
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.getProxyClass(Proxy.java:353)
    at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.newProxyInstance(Proxy.java:581)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BorrowedConnectionProxy.generateProxy(BorrowedConnectionProxy.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.ConnectionManager.borrowConnection(ConnectionManager.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.JDBCContext.borrowConnection(JDBCContext.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:360)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:507)
    ... 8 more
```

The code to start the thread is as follows:

```
MBeanServer server = MBeanServerLocator.locateJBoss();
ObjectName objName;
objName = new ObjectName("jboss.system:service=ThreadPool");
ThreadPoolMBean poolMBean =
   (ThreadPoolMBean) MBeanServerInvocationHandler.newProxyInstance(server, objName, ThreadPoolMBean.class, false);
poolMBean.getInstance().run(runnable)
```

I assume the problem is the differing classloader between the JBoss thread pool and my application (EAR). The problem occurs referencing Hibernate, of which there are two versions in the system (one in JBoss and one in the EAR).

Is it possible to use the JBoss thread pool in this way in JBoss-5? Or do I need to define my own thread pool in the application, maybe in a JCA adapter?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a jboss-app.xml in your ear?  Take a look at this site for JBoss classloading isolation issues  http://community.jboss.org/wiki/ClassLoadingConfiguration

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think in this case the hibernate conflict comes about because I'm explicitly using the JBoss threadPool, and that can not know about the hibernate version in the EAR.